# Cantor's bijection between the sets [0,5] and [12,60]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I mathematically prove that the sets $[0,5]$ and $[12,60]$ have the same cardinality using Cantor's bijection? While simply drawing a linear function seems tempting, my teacher wants us to do so by demonstrating the four following statements:

1. The function is injective.
2. The function is surjective.
3. If $x \in [0,5]$, then $y\in [12, 60]$.
4. If $y \in [12,60]$, then $x \in [0,5]$.

Comment: So you begin by simply defining a linear function, and then check that the properties 1-4 hold for it.

Comment: Draw your linear function, write its equation and show that it has the properties that your teacher wants.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Linear interpolation polynomial.

*Some details:*

The linear polynomial that takes the value $12$ at $x=0$ and $60$ at $x=5$ is:
$$l(x)=60\frac{x-0}{5-0}+12\frac{x-5}{0-5}.$$

Comment: **Hint**: your answer is useless.

Comment: Why that? One has an automatic answer with Lagrange's formula.

Comment: The OP knows about linear functions. They don't know how to prove 1-4. And they don't necessarily know Lagrange's interpolation formula.

Comment: *Linear* interpolation formula? That's from high school –even good level mid schools. As  for properties 1 and 2, they're properties of linear functions, and properties 3 and 4 are by construction (*inter*polation, not extrapolation). You even can choose between order-preserving and order-reversing bijections.